# Iterate through object and add properties to different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If i have four different objects in array, structure like json; How would, you append value of each to object to different div. Every one thank you :)

```
 var obje = [ 
        {name:"nemke", age:12, },
        {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
        {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
        {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
      ]
```

*html*

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

*for example*

```
obje[0].name && obje[0].age goes to first child
obje[1].name && obje[1].age goes to second div
```

I know it;s with `for loop` but i am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of your divs by using something like `getElementsByTagName`, then loop through your object, and assign the value of the array elements to the corresponding divs by using the same array index referenced in your loop.

```js
 var obje = [ 
        {name:"nemke", age:12, },
        {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
        {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
        {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
      ],
    divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < obje.length; i++) {
  divs[i].innerHTML = obje[i].name + obje[i].age;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/j41BsvofELJnQAQYxY8k?p=preview

```
$('.main-div div').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).html(obje[i].name +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ obje[i].age)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for respond, i know how to do it in jquery. Can you please, provide answer in plain old js :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #01 (With jQuery):**

You can use jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method:

```
$.each($('.main-div div'), function(i, elem) {
  $(elem).text('Name: ' + obje[i].name + ', Age: '+  obje[i].age);
});
```

```js
var obje = [ 
  {name:"nemke", age:12, },
  {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
  {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
  {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
];

$.each($('.main-div div'), function(i, elem) {
  $(elem).text('Name: ' + obje[i].name + ', Age: '+  obje[i].age);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Approach #02 (With Pure JavaScript):**

You can select elements with [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate over them using `[].forEach.call()` as shown below:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.main-div div'), function(div, index) {
  div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + obje[index].name + ', Age: '+  obje[index].age
});
```

```js
var obje = [ 
  {name:"nemke", age:12, },
  {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
  {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
  {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
];


[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.main-div div'), function(div, index) {
 div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + obje[index].name + ', Age: '+  obje[index].age
});
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over object keys and use

```
$(".main-div").find("div").eq(key) // in jquery

document.querySelectorAll(".main-div div")[key] // in javascript
```

to append the created html into the existing divs.

```js
var obje = [{
  name: "nemke",
  age: 12,
}, {
  name: "nemkeee",
  age: 1222,
}, {
  name: "nemke1231",
  age: 1221321,
}, {
  name: "nemkasfe",
  age: 32112,
}, ]


Object.keys(obje).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = obje[key];
  var htmlString = "<span>" + obje[key].name + "</span> <span>" + obje[key].age + "</span>"
  document.querySelectorAll(".main-div div")[key].innerHTML = htmlString;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obje = [ 
        {name:"nemke", age:12, },
        {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
        {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
        {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
      ]
 $(".main-div div").each(function(i,div){
 $(this).html("name : " +obje[i].name +" , age : "+obje[i].age);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

In JS:

```js
  var obje = [ 
            {name:"nemke", age:12, },
            {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
            {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
            {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
          ]
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("main-div")[0].children;

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].innerHTML="name : "+obje[i].name+" , age :"+obje[i].age;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="main-div">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need two loops.  One for the array and one for the keys of the objects in that array.

```
var arr = [ 
    {name:"nemke", age:12, },
    {name:"nemkeee", age:1222, },
    {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321, },
    {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112, },
];

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        // logic to append divs goes here
        console.log('<div>' + obj[key] + '</div>');
    })
});
```

produces

```
<div>nemke</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>nemkeee</div>
<div>1222</div>
<div>nemke1231</div>
<div>1221321</div>
<div>nemkasfe</div>
<div>32112</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope it will works for you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6qpc615/2/)

JAVASCRIPT -

```
for(var i=0;i<obje.length;i++){
$('.main-div').find('div:eq('+i+')').append(obje[i]['name'].toString()+' '+obje[i]['age'].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```js
var obje = [{name:"nemke", age:12},
            {name:"nemkeee", age:1222},
            {name:"nemke1231", age:1221321},
            {name:"nemkasfe", age:32112}];
    
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".main-div div");
obje.forEach(function(obj, index, arr) {
  allDivs[index].innerText = obj.name + " - " + obj.age; 
});
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You had some syntax errors on your array.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/b90axrhv/